# Clustered Web host

Tags: web-hosting, looking-for-hosting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

I live in Denmark in the daily and need to find a web host that can keep up at the world level.
Should there be some who is familiar with hotels that can follow the requirements below.

**Overall**

- Clustered Web
- 24/7 Expert Helpdesk and Server Monitoring
- Linux Operating System
- Unlimited Subdomains
- 50 MySQL Databases
- FTP and FTPS Access
- Fast connectivity to any destination - World Wide. (Stable/Low DNS, TTFB and similar)

**Management**

- Full DNS Management
- Web Mail Access
- phpMyAdmin
- Cronjobs

**Mail**

- IMAP/POP3/SMTP
- Mail Auto Responders
- Catch-All Mailbox
- Microsoft Exchange Enabled

**Apache**

- Python and perl CGI Support
- Secure Server (SSL)
- mod_rewrite
- Full .htaccess Support

**PHP**

- PHP v 4.4 & 5.2
- ImageMagick and GD
- CURL
- RTF, POWERPOINT, EXCEL, WORD and PDF parser
- Zip Utility
- xhprof

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Media Temple (http://mediatemple.net/) or Rackspace (http://www.rackspace.com/) should have a solution for you. Of course, everything depends on how much you would like to pay.

Comment: Both of these providers offer a lot of options to scale your application.  Either of these would be a very good choice.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should take a look at https://en.dinahosting.com/
As far as I know, they have many of the things you are asking for.

Comment: These are some good answers. I think I would look at Media Temple.